# eclipse neon remote debug

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

I just installed the latest version of eclipse neon. I previously used eclipse mars. But due to other issues that should be updated in eclipse Neon I changed to this version.

I develop a program for a ARM Linux system on a Windows computer, so using a cross-gcc and doing remote debug using gdb/gdbserver from eclipse. I first made a connection using the remote systems perspective using ftp for file transfer and ssh for the shell. This worked fine and I was happy with this.

But in Neon it seems to be changed because the connection that I made in the Remote Systems explorer can't be selected anymore when you use C/C++ Remote Application Debug. When you look at the connection listbox I only see local connection and not the remote systems anymore. When I create a new connection from the debug configurations dialog I can only choose serial/telnet/ssh but when I choose ssh it doesn't work. I can make the connection and open a command shell, so ssh works. But when it wants to transfer the file to my target it is using sftp appearently (looking at the error log) but I don't have this on my target.
When I transfer the file manually to my target (using the remote systems perspective) the debugging works fine but of course I want to transfer the file automatically when I start a debug.

My question is if indeed this connection management is changed that you can't choose anymore the systems that you defined in the remote systems explorer?
Or do you need install a specific plugin?
The current configuration possibilities are very limited and also the debugging of the issues is limited.

Other solution is that I have scp installed on the target. Is there a way to change from sftp to scp?

Thanks.

Comment: The way to connect to remote systems did change for Neon, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/452356, however this is out of my area of familiarity so I can't actually answer the important parts of your question.

Comment: Johan, thanks for this pointer. Doesn't really help me for a solution but now I see that they changed it. Too bad because maybe the old RSE framework was not good for the programmers it was better for my needs.